# Removing newline before ':' when adding inheritance

Tags: c#, roslyn

With given input like this:

```
namespace Test
{
    using System;

    public class Test
    {
        public int? OBJECTID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I would like to make this class extend other classes. So I wrote my rewriter with these rules:

```
public override SyntaxNode VisitClassDeclaration(ClassDeclarationSyntax node)
{
    node =
        node.WithBaseList(
            SyntaxFactory.BaseList()
                .WithTypes(
                    SyntaxFactory.SingletonSeparatedList<BaseTypeSyntax>(
                        SyntaxFactory.SimpleBaseType(SyntaxFactory.ParseName("Form"))
                            .WithLeadingTrivia(SyntaxFactory.Space) //Space before 'Form'
                            .WithTrailingTrivia(SyntaxFactory.LineFeed) // NewLine after 'Form'
                        )
                )
            );

    return base.VisitClassDeclaration(node);
}
```

But the output I get looks like this:

```
namespace Test
{
    using System;

    public class Test
: Form
    {
        public int? OBJECTID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have tried `WithoutTrailingTrivia()` and `WithoutLeadingTrivia()` in many different locations, but I could not find the real place to put it in, to remove newline before `":"`.

Can you help me with this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I took a look at the Syntax Tree from the example using the Syntax Visualizer from the Extensibility Tools with the caret just behind the class name. This provided me with the following Syntax Tree:

[image]

As you can see the EndOfLineTrivia is associated with the IdentifierToken. Therefore you can remove it (or replace it as shown in the following example) by replacing the identifier:

```
    public override SyntaxNode VisitClassDeclaration(ClassDeclarationSyntax node)
    {
        node = node.WithBaseList(
            SyntaxFactory.BaseList()
                .WithTypes(
                   SyntaxFactory.SingletonSeparatedList<BaseTypeSyntax>(
                       SyntaxFactory.SimpleBaseType(SyntaxFactory.ParseName("Form"))
                           .WithLeadingTrivia(SyntaxFactory.Space) 
                           .WithTrailingTrivia(SyntaxFactory.LineFeed)
                    )
                )
            );
        node =
            node.WithIdentifier(
                node.Identifier.WithTrailingTrivia
                    (SyntaxFactory.SyntaxTrivia(SyntaxKind.WhitespaceTrivia, " ")));
        return base.VisitClassDeclaration(node);
    }
```

Comment: +1. It's sometimes not very intuitive which token the trivia belongs to, but when working a bit with Roslyn this is kinda obvious. After all, the newline was there before, they just added another one and now they're surprised that there are two :-)

Comment: I did not use such tools, and it is more difficult to find it with regular debugging tools. `Identifier` does not have `WithoutTrailingTrivia()` and `WithoutLeadingTrivia()` methods, so that put me off aswell.